# Android WebView: Insert dynamic URL once

Tags: android, url, android-webview

I'm trying to make a WebView which ask user only the first time to insert the URL and then it will be saved and opened automatically on next run.

Comment: Please add the Url in SharedPreference  for the First time when User entered the Url in EditText View and after every time load the url from SharedPreference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SharedPreference:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sp.edit().putString(URL, url).commit(); //save
sp.getString(URL, null); //load
```